# Spring AOP for certain controller class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I have controllers in the same package

```
aa.bb.controller.A
aa.bb.controller.B
aa.bb.controller.C
```

I want to intercept all the calls to A and B, but not C. Because I don't want to use
@Pointcut("within(aa.bb.controller..*), which apply to all three controllers.

2nd question is how to distinguish the request is for A or B.

Updated:

Thanks all for helping! I think it is pretty hard to implement what I originally thought. So I chose to do it separately for different controller. It gets the job done anyway. Hopefully there will be some solution in the future for what I wanted.

Comment: Is there a trait specific to `A` and `B` that makes them eligible for intercepting, which is not shared with `C`? Perhaps you could make that fact explicit by using an aptly-named annotation, and then use that annotation in your pointcut expression?

Comment: How about `within(aa.bb.controller..*) && !within(aa.bb.controller.C)`, if nothing but the class name is specific to `C`? If there is something specific, then please, like @crizzis suggested, explain it by updating the question.

Comment: Concerning your update above: No, it is not hard to implement what you want. You simply decided not to share more information about your case and to ignore all questions. Not the problem is so hard, but you are a little bit too lazy - sorry to be so explicit. I do not mean to be condescending, merely stating a fact. I really wanted to help. However, you need to invest a bit more in order to get a better answer. I even suggested one - no feedback. So thanks for that.

Comment: Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the „execution“ instead of „within“ expression. This will help you to react on specific methode calls.

`@Pointcut("execution(* aa.bb.controller.A.*(..))")`

`@Pointcut("execution(* aa.bb.controller.B.*(..))")`

Here, the first wildcard matches any return value, the second matches any method name, and the (..) pattern matches any number of parameters (zero or more).

If you want to combine them please check following:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* aa.bb.controller.A.*(..))")
public void aMethods() {}

@Pointcut("execution(* aa.bb.controller.B.*(..))")
public void bMethods() {}

@Pointcut("aMethods() || bMethods()")
public void bothMethods() {}
```

Comment: That does not answer the question. Besides, it could be achieved in the same way with `within`.